# How can i access my Status variable in this code?

Tags: android

I've created a variable named **Status** and i want to change it's value in `Report.setOnClickListener()` method. How can i do that?
I have declared Status variable in final but when i want to change it's value, I got error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String Student_Name = "";
    private int Student_Grade = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText studentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText studentGrade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade);
        Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        Button Report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.report);

        final ArrayList<String> infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        final String report = "";
        final boolean Status = true;
        for(int i = 0;Status != false;i++){
            String name = studentName.getText().toString();
            String grade = studentGrade.getText().toString();
            report = name + grade;
            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    infos.add(report);
                }
            });
            infos.add(report);
            Report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReportActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Status = false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: declare it outside oncreate as `boolean Status;`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh   Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable with the `final` keyword, it means that variable's intialization value is infact its **final** value. You can think of it as a ***constant***.

As for your use case, declaring the variable outside the class is the cure.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String Student_Name = "";
    private int Student_Grade = 0;
    private boolean Status = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText studentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText studentGrade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade);
        Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        Button Report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.report);

        final ArrayList<String> infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        final String report = "";
        for(int i = 0;Status != false;i++){
            String name = studentName.getText().toString();
            String grade = studentGrade.getText().toString();
            report = name + grade;
            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    infos.add(report);
                }
            });
            infos.add(report);
            Report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReportActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Status = false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a variable declared as final. Make your status variable as non-final , i.e., just boolean status=true; , and you'll be able to change its value.
If it gives you error that declare it as final, then declare it as a global variable.